# struct member alignment - is it possible to assume no padding

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Imagine a struct made up of 32-bit, 16-bit, and 8-bit member values. Where the ordering of member values is such that each member is on it's natural boundary.

```
struct Foo
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d;
    uint32_t e;
};
```

Member alignment and padding rules are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28VS.71%29.aspx) for Visual C++.   sizeof(Foo) on VC++ the above struct is predictably "12".

Now, I'm pretty sure the rule is that no assumption should be made about padding and alignment, but in practice, do other compilers on other operating systems make similar guarantees?

If not, is there an equivalent of "#pragma pack(1)" on GCC?

Comment: In C, `Foo`, in `sizeof(Foo)`, is not declared. The expression is an error (unless `Foo` is defined/declared somewhere else). I suggest you do not try to write multi-language source files: the cons are much bigger than any pro you might find.

Comment: @pmg: Pedantry. :) `typedef struct Foo{ ... }Foo;`

Comment: I believe the `typedef` is redundant (and therefore a safely removable source of bugs) in C++. My point remains: writing multi-language source files is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On systems that actually offer those types, it is highly likely to work. On, say, a 36-bit system those types would not be available in the first place.

GCC provides an attribute

> `__attribute__ ((packed))`

With similar effect.

Comment: It is not really type dependent, but rather architecture dependent.  For example some 16 or 32 bit processors cannot directly address an 8 bit address, so without padding may have to generate additional shift and mask instructions to extract an 8 bit value from a 16 or 32 bit memory read.  This situation is far more common that your hypothetical 36 bit system (ARM7 for example).

Comment: @Clifford: It's not common. The compiler already has to generate code for addressing an 8-bit type if it exists (because it can never be aligned in arrays), so it's no additional restraint. In general, "the alignment" of a type can never be larger than its size (and must divide its size), so it would be pathological for a compiler to impose larger alignment when the type is used in a struct.

Comment: I was not saying that the compiler could not or would not generate code for 8 bit accesses when necessary, rather for performance reasons it would avoid it for a struct.  An array is guaranteed to be contiguous, a struct is not.  I would suggest that ARM7 is common enough, but since this is tagged Linux, not so much in this context.

Answer (score 8):

In general you are correct that it's not a safe assumption, although you will often get the packing you expect on many systems. You may want to use the `packed` attribute on your types when you use gcc.

E.g.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) Blah { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: This is rather dangerous and completely unnecessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

In practice, on any system where the `uintXX_t` types exist, you will get the desired alignment with no padding. Don't throw in ugly gcc-isms to try to guarantee it.

**Edit:** To elaborate on why it may be harmful to use `attribute packed` or `aligned`, it may cause the **whole struct** to be misaligned when used as a member of a larger struct or on the stack. This will definitely hurt performance and, on non-x86 machines, will generate much larger code. It also means it's *invalid* to take a pointer to any member of the struct, since code that accesses the value through a pointer will not be aware that it could be misaligned and thus could fault.

As for why it's unnecessary, keep in mind that `attribute` is specific to gcc and gcc-workalike compilers. The C standard does not leave alignment undefined or unspecified. It's **implementation-defined** which means the implementation is **required to further specify and document** how it behaves. gcc's behavior is, and always has been, to align each struct member on the next boundary of its natural alignment (the same alignment it would have when used outside of a struct, which is necessarily a number that evenly divides the size of the type). Since `attribute` is a gcc feature, if you use it you're already assuming a gcc-like compiler, but then by assumption you have the alignment you want already.

Comment: With C11 you can also `_Static_assert` that the size of the structure is what you expect.