# Mimick C++ nested structs with union in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I know this question has been asked many times before, and I've tried to read through all the previous questions without much luck.

I am trying to convert the following C++ struct to C#, for use with socket communication.

```
enum class packet_type
{
    read_mem,
    get_base_addr,
    get_pid,
    completed
};

struct copy_mem
{
    unsigned int dest_process_id;
    unsigned long long dest_address;

    unsigned int src_process_id;
    unsigned long long src_address;

    unsigned int size;
};

struct get_base_addr
{
    unsigned int process_id;
};

struct get_pid
{
    size_t len;
    wchar_t name[256];
};

struct completed
{
    unsigned long long result;
};

struct PacketHeader
{
    //uint32_t   magic;
    packet_type type;
};

struct Packet
{
    PacketHeader header;
    union
    {
        copy_mem     copy_memory;
        get_base_addr get_base_address;
        get_pid get_pid;
        completed        completed;
    } data;
};
```

And this is my current C# implementation

```
public enum PacketType
{
    read_mem = 0,
    get_base_addr = 1,
    get_pid = 2,
    completed = 3
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PacketHeader
{
    public PacketType type;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct get_base_addr
{
    uint process_id;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct get_pid
{
    public ulong len;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string name;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct copy_mem
{
    public uint dest_process_id;
    public ulong dest_address;

    public uint src_process_id;
    public ulong src_address;
 
    public uint size;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct completed
{
    public ulong result;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Packet
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] //
    public PacketHeader header;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public copy_mem CopyMem; //28

    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public get_base_addr GetBaseAddress;

    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public get_pid GetPid;

    [FieldOffset(300)]
    public completed Completed;
}
```

I am then using this method to convert the struct to a byte array for the socket transmission:

```
       public static byte[] RawSerialize(T item)
    {
        int rawSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawSize);
        var a = Marshal.SizeOf(item);
        var b = Marshal.SizeOf(buffer);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, buffer, false);
        byte[] rawData = new byte[rawSize];
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, rawData, 0, rawSize);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        return rawData;
    }
```

The issue is that `var a = Marshal.SizeOf(item);` reports a size of `312`, but the actual struct should be `528` bytes when I do `sizeof(Packet)` in C++

Comment: all fields of data in C++ struct  share same storage space, how you implement that in C#?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I came here :)

Comment: they have same offset. also enum class isn't cross-language compatible... network protocols  define field sizes explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions seem to be wrong. First of all, the `wchar_t` type may have different lengths on different machines. On mine, an x64 Linux box, it's 4 byte - that alone makes `get_pid` a `1032` byte sized struct. You might be interested in using a `char16_t` or `char32_t` type instead (see e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t)).

Since the `union` in `Packet` overlaps all fields, this also makes `Packet` a `1040` byte-sized struct: `4` bytes for `PacketHeader`, `1032` bytes for `get_pid` - which is the "longest" struct in there by far - and `4` bytes for padding. Padding, sadly, is platform specific.

To get rid of padding from the C/C++ compiler, you'd need to use attributes such as GCC's `__attribute__ ((packed))` or Visual C++'s `#pragma pack(1)` (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242006/struct-member-alignment-is-it-possible-to-assume-no-padding) SO answer).

Careful though, the field offsets in C# are wrong as well: Except for the header, all field offsets in `Packet` have to be `[FieldOffset(4)]` - since in C++ it's a `union` that starts at byte `4` (assuming zero padding).

For portability, also be aware that an `unsigned long long` is platform specific as well and that the only guarantee for it is to be *at least* 64 bit long. If you need *exactly* 64 bit, you may want to use `uint64_t` instead (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198368/unsigned-long-long-conflict-with-uint64-t)).

---

Here's the code I used to determine sizes (Linux x64, GCC 9.3):

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "packet_type:   " << sizeof(packet_type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "copy_mem:      " << sizeof(copy_mem) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_base_addr: " << sizeof(get_base_addr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_pid:       " << sizeof(get_pid) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "completed:     " << sizeof(completed) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PacketHeader:  " << sizeof(PacketHeader) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Packet:        " << sizeof(Packet) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "wchar_t:       " << sizeof(wchar_t) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With padding (default structs):

```
packet_type:   4
copy_mem:      40
get_base_addr: 4
get_pid:       1032
completed:     8
PacketHeader:  4
Packet:        1040
wchar_t:       4
```

No padding (`__attribute__ ((packed))`):

```
packet_type:   4
copy_mem:      28
get_base_addr: 4
get_pid:       1032
completed:     8
PacketHeader:  4
Packet:        1036
wchar_t:       4
```

---

As was pointed out in the comments, setting the `Packet` struct's `GetPid` field to `[FieldAlign(4)]` will result in the following runtime error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Packet' from assembly 'StructSize, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
```

One way to work around this is to define the `get_pid` struct like so:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public unsafe struct get_pid
{
    public ulong len;
    public fixed byte name[256];
}
```

This is still assuming that the name string is `128` characters long, each of which is a 2-byte Unicode. In doing so, the `name` property is now of type `byte*`. To get back the string, the following two methods should work:

```cs
public static unsafe string GetName(get_pid gp) => 
    new string((sbyte*) gp.name, 0, 256, Encoding.Unicode);

public static unsafe string GetName(get_pid gp) =>
    Marshal.PtrToStringUni(new IntPtr(gp.name), 256);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. If I change the `FieldOffset` for all structs in `Packet`, I get this when I run the app - `Packet is invalid .... because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'
`

Comment: The culprit is the `get_pid` struct's `name` field, this much I can tell.